# Searching mysql database based on completed search

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, arrays, while-loop

I have 3 chain select boxes that return three values from the same line of data in a table: $drop, $drop_2 and $drop_3, and I want to run a mysql query to return a value from another column from that line in the table.  I can "echo" the value directly to the page, but I want to use the array value to then generate matching results from a different table in a "while" loop.  I have the following set up, if anyone can tell me why it doesn't work it would be highly appreciated!

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>

<?php

$search_results = mysql_query("SELECT id_sensor FROM vehicles_new WHERE make='$drop' AND model='$drop_2' AND year='$drop_3'");

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($search_results)){        

    echo $result['id_sensor']; //This is displaying the value I need to use in the next query
    ?>

<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$result'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['part_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>

    <?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance, Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$result'");
```

to this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='" . $result['id_sensor'] . "'");
```

Comment: Vadim is right. That being said, it would be wise to at least use a prepared statement on your queries to help prevent SQL injection. I would also advise moving the PHP code into separate file and call it via a function or object.

Comment: Vadim Baryshev & @Marshmellow1328 Thanks both, it works!  My php/sql knowledge is quite sparse, only started using it a few days ago, do you know of any good resources that I can learn about creating prepared statements and functions from?  Thanks again, Joe